# METEOR: How to manipulate class with session?

Tags: javascript, meteor

i'm currently learning meteor session

When user click All will return like this:

```
<div class="ui secondary pointing menu">
  <a id="all" class="item active">All</a>
  <a id="fiction" class="item">Fiction</a>
  <a id="nonfiction" class="item">Non Fiction</a>
</div>
```

When user click Fiction will return like this:

```
<div class="ui secondary pointing menu">
  <a id="all" class="item">All</a>
  <a id="fiction" class="item active">Fiction</a>
  <a id="nonfiction" class="item">Non Fiction</a>
</div>
```

When user click Non Fiction will return like this:

```
<div class="ui secondary pointing menu">
  <a id="all" class="item">All</a>
  <a id="fiction" class="item">Fiction</a>
  <a id="nonfiction" class="item active">Non Fiction</a>
</div>
```

Here my template:

```
<template name="bookList">
  <div class="ui secondary pointing menu">
    <a id="all" class="item{{selectedTab}}">All</a>
    <a id="fiction" class="item{{selectedTab}}">Fiction</a>
    <a id="nonfiction" class="item{{selectedTab}}">Non Fiction</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here my helpers:

```
Session.set('tabAll', ' active');
Session.set('tabFiction', '');
Session.set('tabNonFiction', '');

Template.bookList.helpers({
  selectedTab: function() {
    Session.get("tabAll");
    Session.get("tabFiction");
    Session.get("tabNonFiction");
  }
});

Template.bookList.events({
  'click #all': function () {
    Session.set('tabAll', ' active');
    Session.set('tabFiction', '');
    Session.set('tabNonFiction', '');
  },
  'click #fiction': function () {
    Session.set('tabAll', '');
    Session.set('tabFiction', ' active');
    Session.set('tabNonFiction', '');
  },
  'click #nonfiction': function () {
    Session.set('tabAll', '');
    Session.set('tabFiction', '');
    Session.set('tabNonFiction', ' active');
  },
});
```

But it's not working. Would be glad if someone correct my mistake

thank You..

Comment: you're not returning the `session.get()` data. You just use you need to do `return Session.get('tabAll');` etc... I will post quick example as answer

Comment: return session get in event not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw many mistakes so here is a simple working example you can see where you did the mistakes

Template call the helper function and give it an argument, in this case what tab we want to check is active.

```
<template name="bookList">
  <div class="ui secondary pointing menu">
    <a id="all" class="item {{selectedTab "all"}}">All</a>
    <a id="fiction" class="item {{selectedTab "fiction"}}">Fiction</a>
    <a id="nonfiction" class="item {{selectedTab "nonfiction"}}">Non Fiction</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

Helper the helper will check if the session value is equals to the tab you're checking for if it's it will return 'active'

```
Template.bookList.helpers({
  selectedTab: function(tab) {
    var activeTab = Session.get('activeTab');
    if (activeTab === tab) {
      return 'active';
    }
  }
});
```

Events just change the session value and it will be changed reactivaly in the template

```
Template.chapterList.events({
  'click #all': function () {
    Session.set('activeTab', 'all');
  },
  'click #fiction': function () {
   Session.set('activeTab', 'fiction');
  },
  'click #nonfiction': function () {
   Session.set('activeTab', 'nonfiction');
  },
});
```

here is a demo app example: http://meteorpad.com/pad/tAsjEJd34YRCfFbeB/BooksList